# Reading string incorrectly from row field using Pypxlib

Tags: python

Heres my code which is similar to the example given here ([Pypxlib on Github](https://github.com/mherrmann/pypxlib))

```
from pypxlib import Table
table = Table(file)
try:
    for row in table:
         print(row['Ident'])
finally:
    table.close()
```

For around half of the table it reads the field correctly, but the other half it gives me some wierd output.

```
~RackC\SGr2\Cmp2\SLA
~RackC\SGr2\Cmp2\Run
~RackC\SGr2\Cmp2\UNL1
~RackC\SGr2\Cmp2\Cycles
Subcool Outlet Temp Rack B
Subcool Outlet Temp Rack A
B03 Fans Rack View

(Name for below) ~EEPR #1 Rack B\Percent Open Valve 3
[~TF:RefrigLib\TSilData_Refrig_Lib~][~P:3~]~EEPR #1 Rack B\[~strHistRefrigLib_cstPercentOpenVlv~]

Subcool Outlet Temp Rack D
D02 Fans Rack View
(Name for below) ~EEPR #1 Rack D\Percent Open Valve 3
[~TF:RefrigLib\TSilData_Refrig_Lib~][~P:3~]~EEPR #1 Rack D\[~strHistRefrigLib_cstPercentOpenVlv~]

Warm Fluid Temp
Warm Fluid 3 Way Valve %
(Name for below) ~EEPR #1 Rack A\Effect SetPt Valve 1
[~TF:RefrigLib\TSilData_Refrig_Lib~][~P:1~]~EEPR #1 Rack A\[~strHistRefrigLib_cstEffectSetPtVlv~]
```

Anyone have an idea on why it could parse the strings like this? I'm trying to parse data that is out of my control so I cant change any of the names of the strings.